# Closest distance to the origin of $(x,y)$ where $y=\frac{4}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm studying calculus vol.1 and one of the questions in a study list is  to **find the coordinate in $f(x)= \frac{4}{x^2}$ that is closest to the origin**. I thought of doing it using derivatives, critic points and inflection points but somehow I can't find anything conclusive! I'm probably forgetting something very dumb but a light in this would help a lot!

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Perhaps you could include at least outlines of your attempts in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The curve you are considering is the set $\lbrace (x, \frac{4}{x^2}) \rbrace$ and the square of the distance of any point (of first coordinate $x$) to the origin is the function: $D(x) = x^2 + \frac{16}{x^4}$ (simply by Pythagores theorem)

If you derive this, you have $D'(x) = 2x - \frac{64}{x^5}$, the zeros of which you can easily determine.

Comment: There seems to be a typo where the derivative of $\frac{16}{x^4}$ should be $-\frac{64}{x^5}$ (notice the exponent).

Comment: Indeed! I fixed that, thanks!